# Conflict between babel-hebrew and arabi

Tags: babel, arabic, hebrew

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    hebrew,% breaks
    farsi,% or arabic
%   hebrew,% compiles
    english]{article}

\usepackage[LAE,LFE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255,utf8,latin9]{inputenc}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

Hello.

\end{document}
```

This breaks with

```
! Argument of \o@everypar has an extra }. <inserted text> 
                 \par  l.126    \n@everypar\expandafter{\the\o@everypar}
```

If `hebrew` is loaded after `farsi`, however, it compiles fine.

It seems to me this is due to a redfinition in `rlbabel.def` (used by Hebrew) that is incompatible with a redefinition in `arabicore.sty` (used by Farsi).

`rlbabel.def` has:

```
\def\rl@everypar{\if@rl{\setbox\z@\lastbox\beginR\usebox\z@}\fi}
\let\o@everypar=\everypar
\def\everypar#1{\o@everypar{\rl@everypar#1}}
```

and `arabicore.sty`:

```
\def\Arabi@rl@everypar{\if@rl{\setbox\z@\lastbox\beginR\usebox\z@}\fi} 
   \let\o@everypar=\everypar 
   \newtoks\n@everypar 
   \n@everypar\expandafter{\the\o@everypar} 
   \o@everypar{\Arabi@rl@everypar\the\n@everypar} 
   \let\everypar=\n@everypar
```

Am I right that the problem is the former definition which adds an argument to `\everypar`? How could this be fixed most elegantly? Even if both packages haven't seen updates for some time I'd like to submit a bug report, but I am not sure to which package. Hints very welcome.

(I know that one can use LuaTeX/XeTeX nowadays, but that's not at stake here. I really try to help fixing this particular case)

**EDIT:** This would be my own humble attempt. This fixes compilation but I am not sure it really does what the original version did:

```
--- /tmp/meld-tmprm047c5p
+++ /home/juergen/texmf/tex/generic/babel/rlbabel.def
@@ -136,8 +136,11 @@
 \def\@ensure@R#1{\if@rl#1\else\R{#1}\fi}
 \def\@ensure@L#1{\if@rl\L{#1}\else#1\fi}
 \def\rl@everypar{\if@rl{\setbox\z@\lastbox\beginR\usebox\z@}\fi}
-\let\o@everypar=\everypar
-\def\everypar#1{\o@everypar{\rl@everypar#1}}
+\let\rl@o@everypar=\everypar
+\newtoks\rl@n@everypar
+\rl@n@everypar\expandafter{\the\rl@o@everypar}
+\rl@o@everypar{\rl@everypar\the\rl@n@everypar}
+\let\everypar=\rl@n@everypar
 \newcommand{\hmbox}[1]{\mbox{\R{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\embox}[1]{\mbox{\L{#1}}}
 \def\@brackets#1#2#3{\protect\if@rl #3#2#1\protect\else
@@ -289,7 +292,7 @@
        \large \bfseries #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss#2}}\par
        \nobreak
          \global\@nobreaktrue
-         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
+         \def\rl@everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\if@rl{\setbox\z@\lastbox\beginR\usebox\z@}\fi}%
     \endgroup
   \fi}}}
 \@ifclassloaded{article}{% article class
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother, I don't see any sensible use case for it nowadays. But if you want to spent your time on it, you should perhaps first ask the maintainer if they will spent their time to apply what ever fix you suggest (or pass over maintainance to you).

Comment: Thanks, but I am really interested in what's wrong here, if only out of curiosity.